# C# Signing XML documents with XAdES

Tags: c#, xml, sign

I need to sign xml with XAdES template. I am using 2 references. The problem is with second, if I add Transform, it will work fine (signedXml.CheckSignature() return True), without this transform it will return False.

my code:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference reference2; 
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml signedXml;
... 
reference2 = new Reference();
reference2.Type = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#SignedProperties";
reference2.Uri = "#SignedPropertiesId";
//reference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform()); IF I COMMENT THIS LINE IT WONT WORK
signedXml.AddReference(reference2);

signedXml.ComputeSignature();
XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

signedXml.CheckSignature(); //return false if dont use Transform in second REF

signedXml.ComputeSignature();
XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
```

second part of signature.

```
<ds:KeyInfo>
  <ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>cert...</ds:X509Certificate>
  </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object>
  <xds:QualifyingProperties Target="#SignatureId">
    <xds:SignedProperties Id="SignedPropertiesId">
      <xds:SignedSignatureProperties>
```

is that problem in .NET ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing it wrong the node for XAdES is in the Signature node, after the object node, you need to compute signature normally then add the object node and the necessary node afterwards, this can be done easily through programing it depends on wut level of XAdES you are going to implement.